Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания. В каком месте нужны запятые?
1. Ничего про него не знаю и тем более почему его статуя была разрушена.
2. А вот где они днём это, пожалуй, нам лучше не знать.


Ничего про него не знаю, и тем более почему его статуя была разрушена.

Пояснение
Предложение нестандартное, так что решение нужно принимать самостоятельно. Т
ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ, частица и союз, в данном случае это частица, которая относится к союзному слову почему и  запятой не отделяется.
Попробуем свести предложение к схеме: Ничего про него не знаю, и тем более это. Конструкция строится по принципу включения: ничего, и это в том числе. Так можно объяснить постановку запятой.

А вот где они днём — это, пожалуй, нам лучше не знать.

Пояснение
Предложение строится по вопрос-ответной схеме: Где они днём? — Это нам лучше не знать. В общем случае ставится запятая, но здесь лучше использовать интонационное тире (много запятых).
При отсутствии местоимения "это" предложение  рассматривается как сложноподчиненное с придаточным изъяснительным в препозиции, в этом случае также возможна постановка тире.
